# why do i get "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" with if statement

Tags: arrays, numpy, if-statement

Im new to programming and im trying to plot a graph where i want my "y" function to differ with a specific condition of x. This is how i tried to do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x= np.arange(0,10,0.1)

if x(x<5):
    y=x
else:
    y=0

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the expression `x(x<5)`.  You used parentheses, so Python is trying to *call* `x` as if it was a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.plot(x, [x_ if x_ < 5 else 0 for x_ in x])
```

The plot method plots x versus y as lines and/or markers. The y array is created based on the values of x array using list comprehension

```
y = [x_ if x_ < 5 else 0 for x_ in x]
```

It is exactly same as

```
y = list()
for i in range(len(x)):
   if x[i] < 5:
     y.append(x[i])
   else:
     y.append(0)
```

Comment: @ DebanjanB agreed, have added it.

Answer (score 0):

The error originates from `x(x<5)`. Python parses the first `x` as a function and try to call it for the argument `x<5`, thus triggering an error, because `x` is not a function that you can call, it's an `numpy.ndarray`, thus explaining the `numpy.ndarray object is not callable` error.

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y = [(xx if xx<5 else 0) for xx in x]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```